# socket.io 404 (Not Found) with extra path

Tags: path, socket.io

I'm setting up a new socket.io project and i can't load the file "socket.io.js"

I have 2 files:

the server file (index.js)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

the client file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO </title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="[HOST DOMAIN]:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I call the client file from path "[HOST DOMAIN]/en/test" and socket.io.js is returning 404 not found.

what could be the error? should i indicate that I am in "/en/test"?

Thanks for help!

Comment: This is incorrect : [HOST DOMAIN]:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js make it simple domain.com/socket.io.js . This is just a js file . Except your http server works on 3000 port.

Comment: change it to `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`